# Buy a domain name (without hosting) and host emails on a different provider

Tags: email, domains, web-hosting

I bought a domain name on a registrar's website for a cheap price but it didn't include hosting.

Now I realized I'd like to have emails sent to `me@mydomain.com`. My friend has a hosting account and he would host my emails for me, but is there any way for him to do so without being in control of my domain?

Note also, that I also can't transfer the domain name to him since I've owned it for less than 60 days

Answer (score 1):

Hosting account is usually a web server. To host email you need an email server. And no, you do not need to transfer the domain, only set MX DNS records to point to email server which will be used to recieve messages for your domain. You will also likely need to setup few extra DNS records (DKIM and SPF for authorization/spam preveintion). All this configuration is email service provider specific and they usually give quite details instructions on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you already own a domain name like yourname.com, you want to use your personalized email address--but you don't want to advertise to the world you're forwarding to and sending those messages from Gmail. While you can manage multiple email accounts inside Gmail by using forwarding, the POP fetcher, and different reply-to addresses, there's an easier way--especially for groups like your family or small business. Google Apps Standard Edition (formerly known as "Google Apps for Your Domain") can host your personal email at Gmail, but without tying you to a gmail.com address for free.

[**Complete Source**](http://smarterware.org/3628/host-your-domain-email-at-gmail-without-forwarding)

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is point the MX record to the mail server that is hosting your mail.

For example in the Bind PRI file you add in the line:

```
yourdomain.com.         IN      MX      0       maildomain.com.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just register your domain, you cant transfer it, you need 60 days and you can transfer it. But, please dont worry as to host with hosting provider, you dont need to transfer your domain. What you need to do is please just **point** your domain to your provider name server. If you unsure about this, you can ask your hosting provider. Gud luck